# How do I properly write to FIFOs in Python?

Tags: python, linux, fifo, mkfifo

Something very strange is happening when I open FIFOs (named pipes) in Python for writing. Consider what happens when I try to open a FIFO for writing in a interactive interpreter:

```
>>> fifo_write = open('fifo', 'w')
```

The above line blocks until I open another interpreter and type the following:

```
>>> fifo_read = open('fifo', 'r')
>>> fifo.read()
```

I don't understand why I had to wait for the pipe to be opened for reading, but lets skip that. The above code will block until there's data available as expected. However let's say I go back to the first interpreter window and type:

```
>>> fifo_write.write("some testing data\n")
>>> fifo_write.flush()
```

The expected behavior is that on the second interpreter the call to `read` will return and we will see the data on the screen, except that is not happening to me. If I call `os.fsync` the following happens:

```
>>> import os
>>> fifo_write.flush()
>>> os.fsync(fifo_write.fileno())
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument
```

And the fifo reader is still waiting. However, if I call `fifo_writer.close()` then the data is flushed. If I use a shell command to feed the pipe:

```
$ echo "some data" > fifo
```

then the reader output is:

```
>>> fifo_read.read()
'some data\n'
```

Has anyone experienced this? If so is there a workaround for it? My current OS is Ubuntu 11.04 with Linux 2.6.38.

Comment: use either "os.mkfifo('fifo')" or in shell "mkfifo fifo"

Comment: `fsync()` on a FIFO makes no sense; none of the data is stored on disc (except *maybe* in swap in very strange situations).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`read()` doesn't return until it reaches EOF.

You can try specifying the number of bytes you want read, like `read(4)`. This will still block until enough bytes have been written, so the producer must write at least that many bytes and then call `flush()`.

Comment: Thanks for that, adding an argument to the 'read' method solved the problem, still needed to flush though..

Comment: @ThiadodeArruda what argument exactly?

Comment: @n611x007: I assume the number of bytes to read as in the example. That's the only documented parameter of ``read()``.

Answer (score 9):

To avoid the need for flushing, open the file without buffering:

```
fifo_read = open('fifo', 'r', 0)
```

That will remove high-level buffering. Data go to the OS directly and, being a fifo, they never get actually written to disk but passed straight to the reader thru the fifo buffer, so you don't need to sync.

Of course, you should have created the fifo first with `os.mkfifo()` or `mkfifo` at the shell, as you pointed in a comment.